# Smack throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory:"

Tags: java, xmpp, classnotfoundexception, smack

So im using Smack to run my chat bot for league of legends, however I can't even get the bot to show up because of a missing class error that I can't seem to figure out. Code and error below, Thanks for any help, -Nick

Also: yes, this code was taken from an example because when I tried it myself I still got the same error.

```
package com.nickparks.bot;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.*;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;

public class JabberSmackAPI implements MessageListener{

    XMPPConnection connection;

    public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.na1.lol.riotgames.com",5223);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            connection.login(userName, password, "xiff");
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void displayBuddyList()
    {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

        System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
        for(RosterEntry r:entries)
        {
            System.out.println(r.getUser());
        }
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        try {
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)
    {
        if(message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: " + message.getBody());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException, IOException
    {
        // declare variables
        JabberSmackAPI c = new JabberSmackAPI();





        // Enter your login information here
        c.login("bot", "Password");

        c.displayBuddyList();

        System.out.println("-----");

        System.out.println("Who do you want to talk to? - Type contacts full email address:");
        String talkTo = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("All messages will be sent to " + talkTo);
        System.out.println("Enter your message in the console:");
        System.out.println("-----\n");

        while( !(msg=br.readLine()).equals("bye"))
        {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

        c.disconnect();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

And here's the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.processConfigFile(SmackConfiguration.java:321)
atorg.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.processConfigFile(SmackConfiguration.java:316)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.<clinit>(SmackConfiguration.java:148)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<init>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:65)
at com.nickparks.bot.JabberSmackAPI.login(JabberSmackAPI.java:16)
at com.nickparks.bot.JabberSmackAPI.main(JabberSmackAPI.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have [XPP3 (XML Pull Parser 3)](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/mxp1/) in your classpath. Smack 4 does no longer bundle it (unlike Smack 3).

I also recommend using a build system with dependency resolution like maven or gradle, which would automatically fetch the required dependencies.

Comment: Yea, I actually have been working on it a lot since I posted this and got it all figured out, made it Maven and downgraded to 3.4 of smack :D

Comment: I don't recommend using Smack 3.

Comment: adding `compile group: 'xpp3', name: 'xpp3', version: '1.1.4c'` to the gradle build file does not fix this issue for me. Any ideas?