# Grails service injection null when injected service has older grails version

Tags: grails, plugins, service, version, code-injection

I have written a Grails Plugin, written in Grails 2.1.1, which offers a service. Now, I have created a new Grails project with Grails 2.4.4 and wanted to inject the service, but this fails.

```
package testproject

class HomeController {

    def myService

    def index() {
        println myService
    }
}
```

Always `null`is printed. I tested this with a Grails 2.4.4 project and with a Grail2 2.4.3 project. When I create instead my Grails Project with Grails 2.1.1 it works.

Why? Shouldn't be a service reachable for newer versions? Do I always have to upgrade the plugin, which contains the service, to be able to use newer Grails versions?

Comment: How do you install the plugin? Do you use it as an inline plugin, or with maven-install, or by releasing to an internal repo (e.g. Artifactory)?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't matter if I use is locally or as maven-install. I tested it on my Mac OS Yosemite with the newest GGTW release but now also on Win7,64bit with tthe ggts 3.6.2 release. I also used grails 2.4.3 for the new project and had also the same problem.

Comment: 2.4.3 is rather buggy (esp. wrt plugins) so definitely use 2.4.4+. Note that re-running `maven-install` doesn't replace existing plugins with the same version, so change the version, or delete the maven local cache dir for that version, i.e. $HOME/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/<pluginname>/<version>/

Comment: You mean, changing the version of the plugin?

Comment: Yes, the `version` property in the descriptor (`FooGrailsPlugin.groovy`)

Comment: I tried it but I get the following error: ´Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ´

Comment: There's no useful information in your comment - stacktraces in Grails need to be read from the bottom up, since they're usually a chain of caused-by exceptions, and the root cause is at the bottom, not the top

Comment: This was a good hint... to read the stactktrace from bottom. I had the problem which was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196588/smack-throws-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserfact And could fix the problem by following the advice of the mentioned thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and it didn't hit me until 2.4.4.  I have a custom security plugin that depends on the Spring Security Plugin.  In my plugin, I'm setting a custom user details service in doWithSpring.  This definition looks like this:

```
    userDetailsService(UserService) {
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        errorService = ref('errorService')
    }
```

I had references to userService in my application and in my plugin.  These references stopped being injected in Grails 2.4.4.  I was able to fix it by replacing these references with userDetailsService.  I don't like this though, because the reference looks like it points to the Spring Security version of this service, and I'm invoking methods that only exist in my UserService class.

Anyways, I'm not sure if it's a bug or bug fix in 2.4.4, but check and make sure that your plugin and/or resources.groovy files aren't redefining your MyService class as something else.